# Plotting attribute of a non-consecutive agentset

Tags: netlogo

How can I plot an attribute of an agentset in netlogo, each with a different pen.
Consider there are other types of agents also, and the who numbers of the agentset to be plotted are not all consecutive to distribution/creation at start.

Comment: What do you mean with _the who numbers of the agentset to be plotted are not all consecutive to distribution/creation at start._ ?

Comment: One cannot use a while loop, for example the starting who number is 25 and there 50 agents. The who numbers of the agents to be plotted are not in between 25 and 75.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that your question is really, "how can I associate each agent in an agentset with a pen?"  Let's call the agentset `myset`.

1. If the agentset is static (no agents created or dying) during the simulation, then you can introduce global `mylst` and set it once to list of agents:  `set mylst [self] of myset`. You can then associate the pens with members of the list anyway you want.  (E.g., you could also make a list of pens so that an agent's index in `mylst` and its pen's index in `mypens` is the same.)
2. You could use `table` and map each pen name to an agent.  (I probably like this solution best.)
3. If these agents constitute a breed, you could give the breed a `pen` attribute that you set to its `pen` name.  (The only reason I dislike this solution is that it meddles with the attributes of the agent purely for GUI purposes, which I try to avoid.)

**EDIT:**

Since you are creating and destroying your agents, but you want each to control its own pen, you have a somewhat weird situation that could lead to a lot of bookkeeping.  I'm going to suggest solution 3: add a `pen` attribute to your agents.  Now each time you create an agent, include as part of its initialization the following:

```
set pen (word "pen" who)
set-current-plot "myplot"
create-temporary-plot-pen pen
plot attribute
```

Here `"myplot"` is the name of the plot you are using for this, and `attribute` is the name of the attribute your are plotting.  Then each tick you can have each of these agents

```
set-current-plot "myplot"
set-current-plot-pen pen
plot attribute
```

If you want to distinguish agents by pen color, you will have to do a little extra work.  (See the `scale-color` command for clues.)

Comment: Does he want to draw on the patches or does he want to **plot** something like a histogram?? I'm confused here.

Comment: @Alan Thanks! You framed the question much better. Could provide some code for the second solution suggested, my agentset is apparently dynamic.

Comment: @DavidMerinos Plot in specific line plot.

Comment: @Alan Can you please explain the second approach with code, I will be able to understand it much better.